# Регулярные выражения: как извлечь телефон из строки?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как получить телефон из строки?

```
$pp = "{ error:{code:0,text:'no'} , on_data : 1, data : {'phone':'+7 906 888-85-02 '} }";
preg_match('/\'phone\':\'(\d+)\'/iU', $pp, $t); echo $t[1];
```

Comment: Вам только цифры или все содержимое со знаками + пробелами дефисами, т.е. +7 906....? если все то `\'phone\':\'(.*?)\'`

Comment: а откуда вы такой кривой json берете?

Comment: А почему нельзя было использовать `json`, чтобы распарсить строку и вытащить телефон?

Comment: К большому сожалению, это не json

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1**

Если это JSON, используйте встроенный в PHP JSON парсер. Подробнее: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

**Вариант 2**

Используйте такое выражение:

```
'phone':'([^']+)
```

*P.S.* в вашем `JSON` значение поля телефон заканчивается на пробел. Сделайте `trim()` после применения регекса.

Используйте [этот сайт](http://regex101.com/) для проверки своих регулярных выражний, если не уверены, что они правильно работают.

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант:

```
preg_match('/\+7 [^\']+/', $your_string, $matches);
echo trim($matches[0]);
```

И хороший интерактивный учебник: http://regexone.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Just for fun**

Текст в вопросе - не JSON, а просто кусок JavaScript-кода.
Можно воспользоваться расширением V8JS из состава PEAR:

```
$v8 = new V8Js();
$pp = "{ error:{code:0,text:'no'} , on_data : 1, data : {'phone':'+7 906 888-85-02 '} }";
$js = "var x = ".$pp.";print(x.data.phone);";
var_dump( $v8->executeString( $js, 'basic.js' ) );
```

Результат `var_dump`:

```
+7 906 888-85-02 int(17)
```

Возвращенное число 17 - длина строки.